# How to set that the referer is the PayPal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, refer

After the PayPal payment it redirects me to the my website. How can I set that user was redirected from the PayPal?

I did try the next variants:

```
request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
request.referer
URI(request.referer).path
```

but nothing.

And one more question, can I catch that the referer is from PayPal exactly or user did it, the redirect, with the online tools, that was it fabricated or no?

Comment: Relying on the HTTP referer is not recommended. Many common clients do not send the `HTTP_REFERER` header.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what PayPal's PDT feature is for. It sends you secure variables about the transaction just made, which you can verify via a postback to PayPal just like PayPal's aynchronous notification system IPN. Here's how:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Comment: but I don't get `at` parameter. I have just tx, st, amt and cc. How can I get `at`?

Comment: At the bottom of the page I referenced above, it has these instructions. The identity token is on the Website Payment Preferences page in the Seller Preferences column. (Although the UI may have been updated since these instructions were written; still, it should be in the prefs pages.)